# Timelock Contract Error

Tags: solidity, erc-20, dao

Can't figure out why this won't compile, possibly due to an upgrade on OpenZeppelin that I'm unaware about.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.17;
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/governance/TimelockController.sol";
contract TimeLock is TimelockController {
   constructor(
    uint256 minDelay,
    address[] memory proposers,
    address[] memory executors
  ) TimelockController(minDelay, proposers, executors) {}

}
```

Here's the error I keep getting:

```
  --> contracts/Timelock.sol:12:56:
   |
12 |   ) TimelockController(minDelay, proposers, executors) {}
   |                                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^


Error HH600: Compilation failed


address[] memory proposers
Wrong argument count for modifier invocation: 3 arguments given but expected 4.solidity(2973)
```

I have no clue what the 4th argument is supposed to be, and haven't found anything on it in the TimelockController docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see, the latest TimelockContract is asking for 4 arguments, rather than 3. So you got to add one more argument for the admin.

```
constructor(
        uint256 minDelay,
        address[] memory proposers,
        address[] memory executors,
        address admin
    ) {}
```

Comment: Yep, that was it.